# loop through password of zipped files

Tags: batch-file

I have many .7z files in `D:/` and it has a password on it which is just a single letter. I want to make a batch file that decompresses the 7z archive attacking it with each possible password (which is a single letter). Currently I want to do it only for one file, namely `old.7z`.

Comment: And what have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code below considering that 7zip is in your PATH.

```
for %%I in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
7z.exe x "D:/old.7z" -p"%%I" 
)
pause
```

If not

```
for %%I in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "D:/old.7z" -p"%%I" 
)
pause
```

Use `7zip.exe` in cmd for the documentation.

Comment: That works. Thanks!! I was wondering if the batch stops automatically after the zip was extracted successfully.

Comment: Will try.. And report